# Integer solutions of an inequality

Tags: roots

Find the number of integer solutions less than $5$ that satisfy the inequality
$$(x^
3 + 4x
2
)(x^
2 − 3x − 2) ≤ (x^
3 + 4x
2
)(2x^
2 − 6).$$

Factoring

$$(x^2)(x+4)^2(x-1)$$

possible integers are  $(-4,0,1,2,3,4)$ but $6$ is not in the choices, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Maybe the book is wrong?

Comment: Source : http://pmo.ph/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/16th-PMO-Qualifying.pdf

Comment: Now we see that your book is wrong. I think your solution is true.